# React App: Windows + Microsoft Edge 95 stable version causes white screen with "Rangeerror: maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: reactjs, windows, react-router, create-react-app, microsoft-edge

My react app is failing to load in the most recent version of Microsoft Edge (version 95), but it only happens on Windows systems. It prints an error in the console "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" but no other errors are returned. This is a weird one, because it only happens on Windows devices (Windows 10 is what i tested in) and only in this specific version of Microsoft Edge. All other versions of Edge and all other browsers work fine, and Microsoft Edge 95 used on a Mac works fine. Additionally, this is not replicable with tools like browserstack for some reason, only on actual laptops.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the issue only occur on one machine or also happen on other machines with same OS and Edge version? Could you please provide a minimal code snippet which can reproduce the issue? With only the text description, it's hard to find the issue. Besides, you can try to clear browser cache and history, then test again.

Comment: Thanks, @YuZhou . Yes, it occurs on other machines with the same OS and Edge version. I am having trouble replicating the issue in a dev environment, however. Browserstack doesn't even pick up the bug. I'll see if i can identify a snippet to use.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like this was a dependency issue on our end. Thanks for looking into this, Yu Zhou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it looks like this was a dependency issue on our end. A dependency we were using in our web app needed to be updated. Thanks for looking into this, Yu Zhou.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @YuZhou, I'll do that.